# How to return a realm object after been created in java

Tags: java, android, realm

I need a to create a method with 2 conditions, first if the object exists in realm, If it exists, return it, if not, create it and then return it.

```
  public RouteModel findOrInitById(final Long webId) {

    Realm realm = null;
    try {

      realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
      RouteModel routeModel = realm.copyFromRealm(
          realm.where(RouteModel.class).equalTo("routeWebId", webId).findFirst());

      if (routeModel != null) {
        return routeModel;
      } else {

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
          @Override
          public void execute(Realm realm) {

            Number currentIdNum = realm.where(RouteModel.class).max("routeId");
            int nextId;
            if (currentIdNum == null) {
              nextId = 1;
            } else {
              nextId = currentIdNum.intValue() + 1;
            }

            RouteModel newRouteModel = new RouteModel.Builder()
                .setRouteId(nextId)
                .setWebId(webId)
                .build();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newRouteModel);

          }
        });
       //here i need to return the "new " object
      }
    } finally {
      if (realm != null) {
        realm.close();
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
```

there is there any way to return the object without a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused... what exactly is your question. I pick your final line

> is there any way to return the object without a query?
>   No. in a realm, you always have to assume other clients to modify your data, thus a query is mandatory

Comment: as you can see in my code, i just created a new realm object inside a transaction, i want to return a copy of the new object without a query

Answer (score 0):

create interface

```
public interface TransactionCallback<T> {
    void onSuccess(T result);
    void onFail();
}
```

then your method would be `public void findOrInitById(final Long webId, final TransactionCallback<RouteModel> callback)`

to call the method write

```
classVariable.findOrInitById(webid,
    new TransactionCallback<RouteModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RouteModel result) {
            // make something
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail() {
            // transaction failed. make toast for user
        }
    }
)
```

by call `callback.onSuccess(newRouteModel)` you send your `realm-Object` to where you call `findOrInitById`

**Caution**: if you make some stuff in `onSuccess`, you are still in `transaction`